# Delphi 10.1 Berlin Fast Report: Database Values not Showing in MasterData Band

Tags: delphi, report, reporting, fastreport, delphi-10.1-berlin

Im a newbie and I was using Fast Report in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. I successfully connected it to my database.

When the text connected to the data set is placed in the `PageHeader Band`, the database value was displayed in the report preview. See images below:

Before Report Preview:

[image]

During Report Preview:

[image]

But when the text is moved to `MasterData Band`, the text is not displayed in the report preview.

[image]

[image]

Why?

Comment: if you execute the program, Can you see the text?

Answer (score 2):

Your masterband is not connected the frxdbdataset1 otherwise you see the name of the dataset in the yellow bar.
Double click on the masterdata and select the dataset

Comment: I have done your suggestion, but it says: "Cannot use the same dataset for Report.DataSet and Band.DataSet", when I tried to preview/run the report.

Comment: Then remove the dataset from Report.Dataset, you don't need that property (in fact I don't know its exact purpose).

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Dataset connected to frxDBDataset1 is open and has at least one record ?

Comment: yes it is open. In fact it shows the record when the text connected to the dataset is displayed on other Bands.